# ArangoDB java driver on executing AQL sometimes return NULL and other times the correct result

Tags: java, arangodb

I am unable to wrap my head around this peculiar issue.
I am using arangodb 3.0.10 and arangodb-java-driver 3.0.4.

I am executing a very simple AQL fetch query. (See code below) All my unit tests pass every time and problem never arises when debugging. The problem does not occur all the time (around half the time). It gets even stranger, the most frequent manifestation is NullPointerException at

```
return cursor.getUniqueResult();
```

but also got once a `ConcurrentModificationException`

Questions:

1. Do I have to manage the database connection? Like closing the driver
   connection after each use.
2. Am i doing something completely wrong
       with the ArangoDB query?

Any hint in the right direction is appreciated.

**Error 1:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.xworx.sincapp.dao.UserDAO.get(UserDAO.java:41)
```

**Error 2:**

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1437)
        at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1471)
        at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1469)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:206)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:593)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:572)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:527)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:507)
        at com.arangodb.entity.EntityFactory.toJsonString(EntityFactory.java:201)
        at com.arangodb.entity.EntityFactory.toJsonString(EntityFactory.java:165)
        at com.arangodb.impl.InternalCursorDriverImpl.getCursor(InternalCursorDriverImpl.java:94)
        at com.arangodb.impl.InternalCursorDriverImpl.executeCursorEntityQuery(InternalCursorDriverImpl.java:79)
        at com.arangodb.impl.InternalCursorDriverImpl.executeAqlQuery(InternalCursorDriverImpl.java:148)
        at com.arangodb.ArangoDriver.executeAqlQuery(ArangoDriver.java:2158)
        at org.xworx.sincapp.dao.UserDAO.get(UserDAO.java:41)
```

**ArangoDBConnector**

```
public abstract class ArangoDBConnector {

protected static ArangoDriver driver;
protected static ArangoConfigure configure;

public ArangoDBConnector() {
    final ArangoConfigure configure = new ArangoConfigure();
    configure.loadProperties(ARANGODB_PROPERTIES);
    configure.init();
    final ArangoDriver driver = new ArangoDriver(configure);

    ArangoDBConnector.configure = configure;
    ArangoDBConnector.driver = driver;

}
```

**UserDAO**

```
@Named
public class UserDAO extends ArangoDBConnector{

    private Map<String, Object> bindVar = new HashMap();

    public UserDAO() {}

    public User get(@NotNull String objectId) {
        bindVar.clear();
        bindVar.put("uuid", objectId);
        String fetchUserByObjectId = "FOR user IN User FILTER user.uuid == @uuid RETURN user";
        CursorResult<User> cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = driver.executeAqlQuery(fetchUserByObjectId, bindVar, driver.getDefaultAqlQueryOptions(), User.class);
        } catch (ArangoException e) {
            new ArangoDaoException(e.getErrorMessage());
        }
        return cursor.getUniqueResult();
    }
```

Comment: The class `UserDAO` is a singleton one as you have declared it `@Named`. So why are you keeping state in this variable `private Map<String, Object> bindVar = new HashMap()` ?? i mean , if it gets called at the same time(in a concurrent environment and not in tests or debugging) i am not so sure what might happen

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *AntJavaDev* said, you access `bindVar` more than once the same time. When one thread modify `bindVar` and another tried to build the AQL call at the same time by reading `bindVar`. This leads to the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

The `NullPointerException` results from an AQL call with no result. e.g. when you clear `bindVar` and directly after that, execute the AQL in another thread with no content in `bindVar`.

To your questions:
1. No, you do not have to close the driver connection after each call.
2. Beside the shared `bindVar`, everything looks correct.